# Elasticsearch settings not applied

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to change the logging level of elasticsearch like this:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
    "transient" : {
        "logger.discovery" : "DEBUG"
    }
}
```

I performed the PUT, and got a response:

```
{
  "acknowledged": true,
  "persistent": {},
  "transient": {
    "logger": {
      "discovery": "DEBUG"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm expecting the log-level to change immediately to DEBUG, but it's still on INFO.
Any ideas, what the problem is, or how to debug this problem?

Comment: What version of ElasticSearch do you use?

Comment: I think this is impossible to change log level on-fly. ES has `static` settings that must be configured for each node and `dynamic` settings that can be overridden using ClusterAPI

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/logging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to set the root log level and not just discovery to debug:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
    "transient" : {
        "logger._root" : "DEBUG"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Elasticserach 5 you need a different command (with full package name in it):

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{"persistent": {"logger.org.elasticsearch.discovery":"DEBUG"}}
```

Relevant documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/misc-cluster.html#cluster-logger

Answer (score 0):

You can change the log level in the following file

```
/etc/elasticsearch/log4j.properties
```

In there, you can change the value for the logger you want, or simply set the `rootLogger.level` to `debug`. Prepare for an avalanche of logs if you do so.

You need to restart the service for this to be effective.

Comment: Quoting https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/logging.html: "You could modify the logging.yml file and restart your nodes—but that is both tedious and leads to unnecessary downtime. Instead, you can update logging levels through the cluster-settings API that we just learned about."